# How to embed Vaadin Composite component created in Visual editor in my webpage?

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I am trying to design a webpage for my website. I am using Vaadin framework and Java Language for the same. I used Visual editor in Vaadin to place the UI elements i.e. I created a composite component. This is done in class MyComponent.java. I have a DownloadManager.java class which extends the UI class and displays the web page. I tried creating an object of MyComponent.java in the UI class so that all the components that I added using visual editor are shown on the web page. But doing this doesn't display anything but a blank page. 
I am pretty new to using Vaadin Framework so kindly excuse if the question is very trivial. I followed Book of Vaadin guidelines for the same but could not find the answer for the above problem.
Below is the code snippet of my classes:

```
public class DownloadmanagerUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = DownloadmanagerUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        //final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        //layout.setMargin(true);
        //setContent(layout);
        MyComponent m = new MyComponent();
        //layout.addComponent(m);
        /*Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

                layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank  for clicking"));
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(button);*/

    }
```

Mycomponent.java:

```
public class MyComponent extends CustomComponent {

    /*- VaadinEditorProperties={"grid":"RegularGrid,20","showGrid":true,"snapToGrid":true,"snapToObject":true,"movingGuides":false,"snappingDistance":10} */

    @AutoGenerated
    private AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;
    @AutoGenerated
    private TextField textField_2;
    @AutoGenerated
    private TextField textField_1;
    @AutoGenerated
    private LoginForm loginForm_1;
    @AutoGenerated
    private Label label_1;
    @AutoGenerated
    private Button button_1;
    /**
     * The constructor should first build the main layout, set the
     * composition root and then do any custom initialization.
     *
     * The constructor will not be automatically regenerated by the
     * visual editor.
     */
    public MyComponent() {
        buildMainLayout();
        setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);

        // TODO add user code here
    }

    @AutoGenerated
    private AbsoluteLayout buildMainLayout() {
        // common part: create layout
        mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        mainLayout.setImmediate(false);
        mainLayout.setWidth("100%");
        mainLayout.setHeight("100%");

        // top-level component properties
        setWidth("100.0%");
        setHeight("100.0%");

        // button_1
        button_1 = new Button();
        button_1.setCaption("Button");
        button_1.setImmediate(true);
        button_1.setWidth("-1px");
        button_1.setHeight("-1px");
        mainLayout.addComponent(button_1, "top:314.0px;left:200.0px;");

        // label_1
        label_1 = new Label();
        label_1.setImmediate(false);
        label_1.setWidth("-1px");
        label_1.setHeight("-1px");
        label_1.setValue("Label");
        mainLayout.addComponent(label_1, "top:82.0px;left:131.0px;");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `init` call: `setContent(m)` (https://vaadin.com/api/7.4.3/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#setContent%28com.vaadin.ui.Component%29)